# Effective search in collection by different properties of element

Tags: c#, performance, search, collections, properties

I need to store many elements in a collection and do searches in it by different properties (about 3-5 props). It will be a list of service clients, some kind of message broker. Properties is a combination of subscriber interests, so each of them will receive messages in which he is interested.

Count of elements/subscribers shouldn't be very big (< 1000).

But there will be many searches (>1000 per second). One search for every message.

Elements in collection considered to be immutable, but collection will always change (new subscribers + unsubscribes). Here will not be high density of subscribes\unsubscribes.

Also it will be good to have a check for element uniqueness. But it`s not necessary, because I can add check before element add.

I wonder what type of collection is better to use to have good search efficiency. Something like HashSet, but with ability to search by different props.
Of course I can create a set of Dictionaries or HashSets for every property but it`s a little bit ugly and hardly maintanable. Better will be to use existing message broker like RabbitMQ or Kafka, but, unfortunately, it's forbidden.

Any suggestions how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple, not optimized approach is to use a list and query with LINQ:

```
var list = new List<Element>();
list.Add(...);
...

Element element = list.Where(e => e.Prop1 == value).FirstOrDefault();
// or
IEnumerable<Element> elements = list.Where(e => e.Prop1 == value);
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a single dictionary for all properties by using a tuple as key as `(propertyName, keyValue)`. The type of the key value would be the common base type of all the properties used as key. If you have, for example, only `string` properties, you can strongly type this key as `string`, otherwise you would have to use `object`.

Using this record (class):

```cs
record Element(string StringKey1, string StringKey2, int IntKey, int Value);
```

Let's make a test:

```cs
var el1 = new Element("aaa", "42", 42, 1);
var el2 = new Element("aaa", "42", 42, 2);
var el3 = new Element("aaa", "42", 42, 3);
var el4 = new Element("xxx", "yyy", 7, 4);
var el5 = new Element("yyy", "xxx", 7, 5);

var dict = new Dictionary<(string, object), Element> {
    { (nameof(Element.StringKey1), el1.StringKey1), el1 },
    { (nameof(Element.StringKey2), el2.StringKey2), el2 },
    { (nameof(Element.IntKey), el3.IntKey), el3 },
    { (nameof(Element.StringKey1), el4.StringKey1), el4 },
    { (nameof(Element.StringKey2), el5.StringKey2), el5 },
};

// Make sure it works with different references.
string s = "aa";
s += "a";

int i = 40;

Console.WriteLine(dict[(nameof(Element.StringKey1), "aaa")]);
Console.WriteLine(dict[(nameof(Element.StringKey1), s)]);
Console.WriteLine(dict[(nameof(Element.StringKey2), "42")]);
Console.WriteLine(dict[(nameof(Element.IntKey), 42)]);
Console.WriteLine(dict[(nameof(Element.IntKey), i + 2)]);
Console.WriteLine(dict[(nameof(Element.StringKey1), "xxx")]);
Console.WriteLine(dict[(nameof(Element.StringKey2), "xxx")]);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Prints:

```
Element { StringKey1 = aaa, StringKey2 = 42, IntKey = 42, Value = 1 }
Element { StringKey1 = aaa, StringKey2 = 42, IntKey = 42, Value = 1 }
Element { StringKey1 = aaa, StringKey2 = 42, IntKey = 42, Value = 2 }
Element { StringKey1 = aaa, StringKey2 = 42, IntKey = 42, Value = 3 }
Element { StringKey1 = aaa, StringKey2 = 42, IntKey = 42, Value = 3 }
Element { StringKey1 = xxx, StringKey2 = yyy, IntKey = 7, Value = 4 }
Element { StringKey1 = yyy, StringKey2 = xxx, IntKey = 7, Value = 5 }
```

as expected.

Comment: It seems OP wants to search on subset of properties, i.e. some of them will not be always present.

Comment: There will always be all properties filled.

Using List+Linq is the first solution, but it will not use any benefits of hash or smth like this, so the serches will cost a lot.

Using object: It would worst because of boxing/unboxing, no?

Using tuple: Will using a tuple as dictionary key provide an efective search in all key by a certain prop?

Comment: Anyway, turning all properties in one string key seems to be working solution.